# Probability in a 6x6 matrix with 6 random ones

Tags: probability

Consider a 6 x 6 matrix, 6 entries are randomly chosen to be "1" and all others are "0". I'm interested in the probability that each row and each column of the matrix contains exactly one "1."

How many possibilities are there to begin with, is it $2^{36}$ or $36 \choose 6$, and why is this the case and not the other? From this, how could the desired probability be computed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of matrices with exactly $6$ ones is ${36 \choose 6}=1947792$ because you select six of the $36$ entries to be ones.  There would be $2^{36}$ matrices if you did not restrict the number of ones.

Of those, there are $6!=720$ that have one $1$ in each row and column.  You have $6$ choices for the $1$ in the first row, then $5$ choices where to put the $1$ in the second row, and so on.